# Access buttons inside a ItemsControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store

I have this code in a windows store project.

```
            <ItemsControl Name="ItemStuff">
              <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <TextBlock Text="lala" Foreground="White" Tapped="SomeFunc"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

I set the items.source of the ItemsControl with a list of 6 items, 
When i tap the textblock i change the Foreground color of the text to Red, but i want to set the others to White, how do i access the other buttons, from a tapped event function, so that when i press the text from the third item, and the first on is already Red, it changes the third to Red and the First to White.

Comment: Stop now and learn MVVM. XAML is very painful to use without MVVM.

Comment: I want to access the 6 TextBlock controls inside a function, not sure how that relates to MVVM

Comment: If you use MVVM, you *won't have* this problem.

Comment: @Ric, why not to use `ListBox` with single selection?

Comment: I need to have the Titles (text inside the TexBlocks) side by side, can i do that with ListBox?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ListBox` in stead of `ItemsControl` as it provides selection functionality and change `ListBoxItem.Template` which will turn `Background` red when it is selected

```xml
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
      <ItemsPanelTemplate>
         <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
      </ItemsPanelTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                  <Grid>
                     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                           <VisualState x:Name="Unselected" />
                           <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                              <Storyboard>
                                 <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="PART_Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                       <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                          <SolidColorBrush Color="Red"/>
                                       </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                 </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                              </Storyboard>
                           </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                     </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                     <Border Background="White" x:Name="PART_Border">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                     </Border>
                  </Grid>
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <TextBlock Text="lalala" />
      </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```